# How to prevent a terraform resource from being deployed after it shows up in the planned diff?

Tags: intellij-idea, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, vpc, terraform-template-file

I ran into this situation during my training the other day.

Say im working with another guy on a terraform infrastructure, and we have shared state (ofcourse).

He creates a resource and updates the state but doesnt deploy that said resource.

After which I code an important resource and want to deploy it, but i dont want the changes the other guy made to *apply* along with my resource.

What would be the ideal solution for this?

- Seperate workspace?
- Taint his resource?
- Remove his resource from the state file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible:

> "He creates a resource and updates the state but doesn't deploy that
> said resource."

The state file tracks what is deployed. How would the state be updated with that resource, if the resource wasn't deployed?

> What would be the ideal solution for this?
>
> Seperate workspace?

If you are both working on resources that belong in the same environment, then that's probably not the right solution.

> Taint his resource?

Tainting a resource causes an already deployed resource to be deleted and redeployed. How would that help the situation you describe?

> Remove his resource from the state file?

You should never modify the state file directly.

---

Are you confusing the Terraform template files (.tf files) with the Terraform state file?

---

I'm guessing you have some terminology wrong, and what you mean to say is the resource is defined in the Terraform template, and now you need to deploy something new without including that other resource. In that case you would need to use the [-target argument](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/resource-targeting?in=terraform/state&utm_offer=ARTICLE_PAGE) to deploy only certain resources.

Comment: No i was talking about statefiles (.tfstate), the issue i was facing was that the unwanted resource was showing up in `terrafrom plan` / `apply` but it wasnt deployed.
Ill look into --target argument tho, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case because there is one state file and more than one developer contributing, the use of workspaces would be best. That way both will get working sessions of the resources being deployed. Note, if you decide to go the workspace route, doing a migration of the default workspace would be needed into the new workspace. This [guide](https://dev.to/igordcsouzaaa/migrating-resources-from-the-default-workspace-to-a-new-one-3ojc) can help with that.

Comment: Wouldnt the unwanted resources be added to the new workspace state? Or should one just create a temporary workspace for a single deployment?

Comment: The unwanted resource would be added to the new workspace. After you do a migration from the default workspace, I would then just remove the unwanted resource from the workspace the state file was migrated to. The benefits of doing that is you can work within your own workspace and not manage things you don't want. Here is a link to removing resources from a state file. https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/rm

Comment: So the the solution would be to use seperate workspaces from the start, but in this case create a new workspace and `rm` the unwanted resource?

Comment: Separate workspaces from the start would have been solution. Or as a work around you can leave the other developer’s resource in the code and deploy the resource you need deployed by utilizing the target option terraform has. https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/resource-targeting-in-terraform

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).